# jQuery datatable and different types of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I am struggling with jQuery Datatables and some jQuery. I have a bootstrap button that when clicked opens a specific modal using the `data-target` attribute:

```
<button type='button' id='Table' class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ModalDeactivate'>Active</button>
```

At the moment I am currently just putting the button in the `defaultContent` of the datatable. This turns all the buttons in the datatable to a green success button and when clicked launches the modal which is fine.

However I have two `sName` data fields `Pending` and `Activated` and I want to make it so that if `Activated` is set to `1` then I use the button described above, if `Pending` is set to `1` then I use:

```
<button type='button' id='Table' class='btn btn-warning' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ModalActivate'>Pending</button>
```

Notice the button `class` and `data-target` has changed. How can this be achieved? The [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) states you can use the data field (in my case set to `null` at the moment)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "Data/AjaxHandler",
        "aoColumns": [
                        { "sName": "Pending" },
                        { "sName": "Activated" },
                        {
                            "sName": "Activate/Deactivate",
                            "targets": -1,
                            "data": null,
                            "defaultContent": "<button type='button' id='Table' class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ModalDeactivate'>Active</button>"
                        }
                    ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly - that is you want to display a button in the last  based on the first 2 row values - you can use [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) for this:

```
{
"targets": -1,
"data": null,
"render": function ( data, type, full) {
        if(full[0] == '1'){
            return "<button type='button' id='Table' class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ModalDeactivate'>Active</button>";
        }
        if(full[1] == '1'){
            return "<button type='button' id='Table' class='btn btn-warning' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ModalDeactivate'>Pending</button>";
        }
    }
}
```

`full[1]` and `full[2]` are the Pending and Activated row values which you check before rendering the button.

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/9jf2k53p/140/) for a working example

Comment: This is great I think this pretty much answers the question but one quick question if I dont display pending or activated can this method still work?

Comment: It should work as-is. `full` is the full data source for the row, so `full[1]` is the first value, `full[2]` is the second etc. Actually, I think it's zero-indexed, so the first value would be `full[0]` and so on.

Comment: Yeah I gathered that, my concern tho is I am thinking of not displaying those fields in the table. So just wanted to find out if it takes from the datasource and not the actual rendered table. As "render" is abit misleading.

Comment: They're not displayed values necessarily, but they are in the row's datasource